# Capture Checkbox event from ListView

Tags: powershell, xaml

I'm working on a GUI interface for my collegue and I want to add a ListView with checkboxes and "make stuff" when the users are checking the checkbox.

[image: Capture from my "training" GUI]

I've done a lot of search on StackOverflow and Technet and so far, I only got some checkbox that I can set (with binding) like I want, but I'm unable to create or capture any event on the check event.

I've made a little GUI interface to do my trial and error. So my XAML code looks like this :

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:GUI_Techgenix"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="Powershell GUI Training" Height="250" Width="400">
    <Grid>
        <ListView x:Name="listSort" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="132" Margin="15,15,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="350">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView AllowsColumnReorder="true" ColumnHeaderToolTip="InfoPaquet">
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Play">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Play}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=PkgName}">
                        <GridViewColumnHeader>Package Name</GridViewColumnHeader>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=ProgramName}">
                        <GridViewColumnHeader>Program Name</GridViewColumnHeader>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=SequenceID}">
                        <GridViewColumnHeader>SequenceID</GridViewColumnHeader>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

And my Powershell code looks like this :

```
Set-Location $PSScriptRoot
#Loading modules
#Module to import XAML inspire by these nice walkthrough :
    - https://foxdeploy.com/2015/04/16/part-ii-deploying-powershell-guis-in-minutes-using-visual-studio/
    - http://techgenix.com/building-powershell-gui-part2/
Import-Module .\XAML-Loader -ErrorAction Stop

$mainWindow = Open-XamlForm(".\FormTest.xaml")

$testobj = New-Object -TypeName PSObject
$testobj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name ("PkgName") -Value "Test"
$testobj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name ("ProgramName") -Value "Install"
$testobj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name ("Play") -Value "True"
$mainWindow.listSort.AddChild($testobj)

$testobj2 = New-Object -TypeName PSObject
$testobj2 | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name ("PkgName") -Value "Test2"
$testobj2 | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name ("ProgramName") -Value "Install Notes"
$testobj2 | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name ("Play") -Value "False"
$mainWindow.listSort.AddChild($testobj2)

$mainWindow.listSort.add_MouseLeftButtonUp({
    Write-host "ClickThatUp!"
})

$mainWindow.XamGUI.ShowDialog() | Out-Null
```

The `add_MouseLeftButtonUp` works great everywhere in the listview, except the checkbox.

Comment: Have you tried using the PropertyChanged event on the view column? `$mainWindow.listSort.View.Columns[0].add_PropertyChanged({<stuff>})`

Comment: Sadly, it doesn't seems to work. The "propertychanged" event is only triggered when the window is loaded from what I can see. But I'll continue to "play" with the column, we never know...;)

Comment: Have you considered adding event triggers to the individual items?

Comment: I tried with my little experience, and with exemple from the web, and I always hit the same "Impossible to create 'Handler' from text 'xxxxx'" errors. All example seems to come from C#, but I've found nothing for custom event for Powershell.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want XAML UI, then this answer is not applicable.  Personally, I never attempt to write GUI in PowerShell...

Have you considered Out-GridView?

```
$data = @(
[PSCustomObject]@{Name='Name1'; Description='Description1'}
[PSCustomObject]@{Name='Name2'; Description='Description2'}
[PSCustomObject]@{Name='Name3'; Description='Description3'}
)
$data | Out-GridView -Title MyTitle -OutputMode Multiple
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer! I already use Out-Gridview for some "quick info", but in my case, the listview is only a small part of a bigger "tool" i'm developping, so I can't use it.